# How to hash a row in Python?

Tags: python, hash

I am trying to implement the following algorithm in Python [[1]](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1175&context=cstech):

> **The problem**: (row compression) Let `A` be an `n x m` array of bounded degree d (i.e., each element of `A` is an integer, `a`, such that `0<a<d`.), and let `k` be the number of distinct rows of `A`. Find a `k x m` array, `A'`, such that each row of `A` appears in `A'`.
>
> ---
>
> **The Method**: (Hashing) Hash the rows of `A` into a table, skipping duplicates and adding the rest to `A'`.

I do not understand how to hash a row in Python?

Well, I would like to understand what does it mean by "hash the rows of A into a table". What I understand is the following. Suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [6, 7, 5, 4]]
```

So, I hash its rows (somehow) and I get:

```
B = [x1, x2, x3]
```

where `xi` is the hash of row `i`. Here I will have `x1=x2` since the row 1 and the row 2 are equal. Since I get `x1=x2`, I will keep one and I finally have:

```
A' = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
      [6, 7, 5, 4]]
```

Am I right? If so, how can I implement such an algorithm in Python?

Thanks.

---

[1] D. Comer, "Removing Duplicate Rows of a Bounded Degree Array Using Tries", Purdue University, 1977 .

Comment: Are you looking for a dict?

Comment: I think. Is it a hash table?

Comment: yes it is what you would use for a trie in python

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to remove the duplicated rows. For that aim, you can use `set` but first you need to convert all your rows to immutable object types.

You can convert them to `tuple` :

```
>>> A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
...      [1, 2, 3, 4],
...      [6, 7, 5, 4]]
>>> 
>>> map(tuple,A)
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 5, 4)]
```

Then you can use `set`. And as `set` uses hash function, the result will be hashed automatically :

```
>>> set(map(tuple,A))
set([(1, 2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 5, 4)])
```